# How to create ListView item that match material guideline

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

How to create ListView like this, [image]

google has documentation about this,

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing

But there is no explaination how to make this,

Here is my attempt so far, I'm not sure about the margin/padding and the separator, is there any tutorial how to make this layout

This is the RecyclerView item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:transitionName="parent_view"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_layanan"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:transitionName="image_layanan"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_layanan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_layanan"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_layanan"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:transitionName="text_layanan"
        tools:text="string/item_title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_dokter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_layanan"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_layanan"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_layanan"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:transitionName="text_dokter"
        tools:text="string/item_desc"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_jam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_dokter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_layanan"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_layanan"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:transitionName="text_jam"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pasien"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_jam"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_layanan"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_layanan"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:transitionName="text_pasien"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_pasien"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text_pasien"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_pasien"
        android:background="#212121"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to know ? Just about design part ? Or the complete implementation in java

Comment: The design part, I don't think my design is right.

Comment: such as the divider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get partial divider (or whatever the name) I use this:

create a class extend `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

```
public class RecyclerViewItemDivider extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{android.R.attr.listDivider};

    private Drawable mDivider;

    public RecyclerViewItemDivider(Context context) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
        mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        // this is the left start point for divider, 
        // I think there is better method without hardcoded the view
        // main_content is my RectclerView item main content
        // R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin should be 16dp if use google guidelines
        int left = (int)parent.findViewById(R.id.main_content).getX() +
                (int)parent.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to use it like this:

```
RecyclerViewItemDivider divider = new RecyclerViewItemDivider(recyclerView.getContext());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);
```

Comment: placing the parents layout as part of the solution makes it unusable for me. Views need to be generic.